# Asyncio | How to resolve "a coroutine was expected" error?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, bluetooth, python-asyncio

I grabed the two_devices.py code example from here:
https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/blob/develop/examples/two_devices.py

When I try to execute it, I receive the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
a coroutine was expected, got <_GatheringFuture pending>
  File "path to file", line 39, in <module>
    "F0CBEBD3-299B-4139-A9FC-44618C720157",
ValueError: a coroutine was expected, got <_GatheringFuture pending>
```

Can anyone provide some suggestions how to resolve this?

Comment: Ask the maintainer why that is happening. Look through or step through the code and try to figure out why the wrong object is being passed

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask], [mre] and the other links found on those pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked code is incorrect. It's calling a synchronous function with `asyncio.run`, and it's never `await`-ing on `asyncio.gather` (and you *can't* use `await` in a synchronous function).

A correct implementation would look something like this:

```
...

async def main():
    return await asyncio.gather(*(connect_to_device(address)
                                  for address in addresses))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(
        main(
            [
                "B9EA5233-37EF-4DD6-87A8-2A875E821C46",
                "F0CBEBD3-299B-4139-A9FC-44618C720157",
            ]
        )
    )
```

---

This is still problematic -- it will run, but the code never does anything with the return value from `main`.

Comment: Is there some reason that you can't just `asyncio.run(asyncio.gather(...))`?

Comment: That would also work, but the original code had a `main` function.